# How to get String-Array referenced by another String-Array?

Tags: android, arrays

For example if I have the following `String_Array`

```
<string-array name="recipe_ingredients">
    <item>@array/m1_ingredients</item>
    <item>@array/m2_ingredients</item>
</string-array>
```

How can I access `@array/m1_ingredients` where it is another `String`_Array

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :
No, every item of a `StringArray` must always be a String, of course. So it can't be another `StringArray`

check the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) on resources, scroll to StringArray

> name
>       String. A name for the array. This name will be used as the resource ID to reference the array.

here's an eg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

> This application code retrieves a string array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Comment: So is it possible to access Array-String from another Array-String ?